# React-Native IOS real device does not connect to Metro server

Tags: xcode, react-native

My Simulator works fine it connects to the development server first try. But on my real device I have to *delete node modules, reinstall Podfiles, clean building folder and delete Derived Data then it loads a bunch of time in Xcode and finally connects to dev server*. But after I stop it and I want to run it again it wont connect. I used to able to just run **npm start** and launch my app on my phone and it connected automatically, and I could make changes, it refreshed and everything, but now even with Xcode running it doesn't work 10/9 times.

And yes I'm on the same network with my phone as the computer. I tried to set my mac's IP on Bundle Settings on the phone, no success.

Anyone got any idea?

Answer (score 29):

Have the same problems. These are my steps to 'fix' this:

- Ensure that you don't have ethernet internet cable plugged in. Only wifi network (iPhone and Mac has to be on the same wifi network)! I think that this was the main problem in my situation.
- Turn off the metro, the app usually starts (because the native app build contains also js build).
- Then run the metro again.
- Shake your device and `Configure Bundler` with your Mac's IP
- it seams that only resave of this screen helps - so you don't have to spend time with finding and entering the IP
- Then it should connect to your metro

I spent hours trying all possible fixes...

Another hints:

- https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/29587
- https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/29396
- delete pods file
- update ios pod
- cleanup DerivedData
- update react-native (I don't have problem with clean RN app)
- update xCode, iPhone, Mac
- try different iPhone device

Comment: Configure Bundler with my Mac's IP worked for me

Comment: thanks. you're first point helped me out! my mac and iphone were connected to different networks, hotspot and wifi.

Comment: My WeWork's wifi was interfering somehow. Got around this by plugging my laptop into ethernet and having my laptop share that connection over wifi with the ipad.

Comment: Also, try to disable your VPN, it's can be reason

Answer (score 13):

For me it was the XCode build which was targeted for `Release`, not `Debug`.

Simply navigate `Product > Scheme > Edit Scheme` and change the `Build Configuration` to `Debug`.

Answer (score 7):

The only thing the predictably works for me is connecting with the mac to the iphone's hotspot.

Not ideal, but nothing else worked for me ‍♀️

I'm on m1 in case it matters

Answer (score 6):

Once the app is launched shake the device to enter the dev menu, click configure bundler and put the IP address of the machine running metro. Mine was set to default `localhost`. There is also a `metro.config.js` that I think you can set this up to use a spec.

If you're on a mac the local IP address can be found in system pref -> network -> WIFI

Comment: Doing this same thing, but simply hitting "reset to default" instead of my actual IP worked for me.

Comment: how to do this ?

Comment: Same as @lambinator! Just tapping "reset to default" worked for me. Crazy!

Answer (score 6):

- Make sure your Mac and iPhone are connected to the same wifi.
- In your xcode go to:
  Window -> Devices and Simulators -> click on your iPhone-> make sure `Connect via network` checkbox is checked.
- Shake your iPhone -> in the poped up modal select `Configure bundle`
- Press and hold `Option` key and click on your wi-fi icon in the menu bar. Under your wifi network there will be your IP address. Paste it to the modal from previous step. No need to specify port and file name.

Answer (score 4):

Turn off/on wi-fi on device / on mac, rebuild app

Comment: This one worked for me. I finally got to rest after 2 sleepless days.

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me after trying everything else.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure the **Local Network** permission is enabled for the app; otherwise iOS won't be able to access your Mac and the jsbundle

Answer (score 3):

If you're on:

IOS: 16.0 >

XCode: 14.0 >

Make sure your iPhone and Mac are on the same wi-fi.
Go into XCode > Click your project > Build Phases > Bundle React Native Code and Images > tick the box for 'For Install Builds Only'.

If it's already ticked, untick the box then build. Then re-tick the box then build again.

Your app should request local network access this is the key fact with this issue. You can check in the settings of your app on the iPhone.

Answer (score 2):

For me it was enough to remove node_modules folder

```
rm -rf node_modules
```

Then I have run

```
npm install; 
npm start -- --reset-cache;
```

And reinstalled pods

```
cd ios; rm -rf Podfile.lock Pods; pod --repo-update install; cd ..;
```

Answer (score 1):

On iOS 16 the real device can't connect on metro bundler. To verify this, open safari and enter your mac's IP, eg. `192.168.1.10:8081` (`8081` is the bundler port), if the page won't load then there's a network issue.

Solution:
Untick the `Disable unless needed` checkbox under Mac network settings:
[image]

This will put the iOS device in hotspot mode but the mac will continue using the WiFi connection for internet browsing. Don't know what kind of sorcery this is but it works.

Answer (score 1):

I was on different wifi connections was the issue for me.
Switched to same wifi and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

As a rule of thumb whenever running an app on iOS device, or even a simulator I've used before I uninstall the app before running again.

Unsure if you had a previous version in this instance but worth a shot in the dark.

I find running via Xcode rather than `react-native run-ios` is more consistent also.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me after trying everything I could, was creating a file `main.jsbundle` inside the `ios` folder, adding to the XCode project and target the file with the application using the `Target Membership` section (in XCode)